# Fields and Galois theory.

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field

I have read Galois theory by Joseph Rotman and it's very well written. Now I want to read field theory and galois theory more formally. A guy recommended me the book 'Field extensions and Galois theory' by Julio R. Bastida. Is it a book to start with? I can't find it online. Any more suggestions will be appreciated and please tell me if there's any free online source for this book.

Answer (score 0):

I think *Galois Theory* by Ian Stewart is a great book if you want to study Galois Theory formally. It is also very detailed and understandable. You can download it for free online, in pdf format.

Comment: Does it include enough theory of field extensions?

Comment: Yes, it definitely does. It is a very good book to learn about these topics, in my opinion. The titles of some of its chapters are: 4) Field extensions, 5) Simple extensions, 6) The degree of an extension, 17) Abstract field extensions and 23) Algebraically closed fields (it has 24 chapters in total), so I think you can find there what you need.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will deinitely take a look.